# How do I remove labels based on certain conditions in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am doing the #duboischallenge and am on challenge 5.

I would like to remove the labels "0%" on the plot.

code (still learning so might not be most efficient code!):

```
income <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-02-16/income.csv')


data5 <- income %>%
  gather(expenses, percentage, 3:7) %>%
  mutate(percentage = replace_na(percentage, 0))

data5$expenses <- factor(data5$expenses, levels = c("Other", "Tax", "Clothes", "Food", "Rent"))
data5$Class <-factor(data5$Class, levels = c("Over $1000", "$750-1000", "$500-750", "$400-500", "$300-400", "$200-300", "$100-200"))

plot5 <-ggplot(data5, aes(x = Class, y = percentage, fill = expenses)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "blueviolet", "darksalmon", "azure3", "cornsilk3"), breaks = c("Rent", "Food","Clothes", "Tax", "Other"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Class, y = percentage, label = paste0(percentage, "%")), color = if_else(data5$expenses == "Rent", "white", "black"), size = 3.5, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]
If I add

```
geom_text(data = data5 %>% filter(percentage > 3),aes(x = Class, y = percentage, label = paste0(percentage, "%")), color = if_else(data5$expenses == "Rent", "white", "black"), size = 3.5, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

I get this error:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32): colour

How do I remove the "0%" labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take the same approach like with colouring the labels:

```
  ggplot(data5, aes(x = Class, y = percentage, fill = expenses)) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "blueviolet", "darksalmon", "azure3", "cornsilk3"), breaks = c("Rent", "Food","Clothes", "Tax", "Other"))+
    geom_text(aes(x = Class, y = percentage, 
                  label = ifelse(percentage > 0, paste0(percentage, "%"), "")),
              color = if_else(data5$expenses == "Rent", "white", "black"), size = 3.5, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple solution!