# How prevent labels from getting clunked in stacked bar chart in R (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, visualization

I've been trying to solve these percentage labels that are thrown out of the image and don't show correctly when the number is too low, but can't seem to find a solution.

You can see it in the right side of the image, alternatives C and D usually get pushed together and you can't read the percentage in the geom_text label.

My df, "bloco", is composed of the following columns:
-Item: questionnaire item, e.g. one question
-Alternative: each alternative for the respective item
-p: percentage of answers for that alternative in that item
-Block: which block the item belongs to

```
bloco %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = as.factor(Item), x = p, fill = Alternative, group = Block)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = as.factor(Item), x = p, label = p),
    # position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    size = 2.5
  ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = p),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    size = 3,
    color = "#413F1A"
    # nudge_x = -1,
    # hjust= 1
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = ''
    , values = c(
      '(A) Nunca ou quase nunca.' = '#F9E79F',
      '(B) De vez em quando.' = '#F7DC6F',
      '(C) Quase sempre.' = '#F4D03F',
      "(D) Sempre." = "#F1C40F"
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = label_wrap_gen(25))+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100), limits = c(0, 1.02)
                     )+
  labs(#title = paste0("Gráfico ", ngraf,  ": Percepção dos professores sobre a segurança no contexto escolar."), 
    x = "Frequência de Respostas (%)", y = "") +
  theme_test() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11)
        , legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm')
        , legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image: My answer pattern chart]

I've already tried vjust and positioning them manually, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have your data, so we need to create something similar to demonstrate the problem and solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(category = rep(letters[1:5], each = 5),
                 response = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 5), 
                 vals = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.35, 0.05,
                          0.01, 0.01, 0.08, 0.8, 0.1,
                          0.01, 0.1, 0.19, 0.68, 0.02,
                          0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
                          0.01, 0.02, 0.87, 0.08, 0.02))

ggplot(df, aes(vals, category, fill = response)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(vals, 0.1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = rev(c('#F9E79F', '#F7DC6F', '#F5D853',
                                     '#F4D03F', "#F1C40F"))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

The typical way to fix this issue (assuming you do not want to select a different type of plot), would be to use `geom_text_repel` in place of `geom_text`

```r
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(vals, category, fill = response)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = scales::percent(vals, 0.1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = 'y') +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('#F9E79F', '#F7DC6F', '#F5D853',
                                     '#F4D03F', "#F1C40F")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Just for reference, best solution I found was to supress small values (say, smaller than 1%): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372501/how-do-i-remove-labels-based-on-certain-conditions-in-ggplot2